# Permalinks without post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I use norebo theme

I use it when I open a Portfolio the link is in this format

```
https://www.hshnorm.com/project/fruit-flavored-powder-juice/
```

How can I remove the word `project`

To be the link in this format

```
https://www.hshnorm.com/fruit-flavored-powder-juice/
```

Answer (score 0):

is `project` a custom post type?
if so, it's been answered here [Custom Post Type URL Rewriting?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53298/custom-post-type-url-rewriting)

but, if that is a regular post, it would be in the `Settings > Permalinks` to set the permalinks.

Comment: "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "project", "with_front" => true ),  "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "/", "with_front" => true ),

Comment: yes, make it ```'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects','with_front' => false),```

Answer (score 0):

use the str_replace.

```
$a = 'https://www.hshnorm.com/project/fruit-flavored-powder-juice/';
$b = str_replace( 'project/', "", $a );
echo $b;
```

Comment: I'd guess it's not that simple: I assume the problem is configuring WordPress so that get_permalink() doesn't generate the /project/ in the first place - or whichever prefix - and so that it accepts routes without it correctly too.

Comment: it's very possible, in that case the code generated is on a folder call project inside the active theme, maybe retriving it from that folder has the effect desired. But it would be better if it could be done on the dashboard, I dont know how..